# website layout issue & best practice when designing the main template

Tags: html, css

I want to have a website layout with

- Header section full width
- Content Area Center with 870px width with Content bar & widget bar
- Footer section with 100%
- Copyright bar at bottom with 100%

Sample design is setup at fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7zavu4f4/

For some reason Footer section is not showing up and i want to know if this design temple is flexible to adjust contents in content area of varying height.

Has this been design in a good way or i need to make any changes to make it clean.

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="search-bar">Search control will be on right</div>
    <div class="logo-Wrapper">Logo Will Be here</div>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>

            </li>
            <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-bar"></div>
    <div class="widget-bar"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer-wrapper"></div>
<div class="copyright-wrapper"></div>
```

I don't need a responsive version for this as we have a separate mobile version of this website based on Mobile jQuery.. So please only take desktop version into consideration

Comment: please share your css codes or a fiddle demo.

Comment: Oops Missed that one http://jsfiddle.net/7zavu4f4/

Comment: "For some reason Footer section is not showing up" - because your footer and copyright div's don't have height(0px), I've set 5px top and bottom padding for demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7zavu4f4/1/

Comment: Good pick, but is the layout design fine..

Comment: yea, It's just fine, but you should use `display:inline-block` instead of `float`, don't mind it's fine

Comment: very good tip.. `display:inline-block`

Comment: I am not sure why it as marked -ve, as this can be very helpful to other..

Comment: don't worry, you've my +ve :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested your design out different browsers and different screen sizes? PCs and Macs? Android? iOS?

Rather than having a specific mobile version, it is much better to make your standard website look good at all screen sizes. Not everyone has a browser window of 870px width -- you have to consider how the page will look on a 1920x1080 screen or a 1440x900 screen as well as a narrow phone viewport. Some things to consider might be whether you want to make your main content wider on large screens and put the widgets outside the central coloured content area.

If you want to improve your markup (i.e. the html), have a look at the html5 specs, and particularly at the semantic tags such as `<article>`, `<section>`, `<header>`, and `<footer>` -- it is more semantically appropriate to use those elements than a load of `<div>`s . There is an excellent list of html5 resources at [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/resources).

Comment: **OP** - "I don't need a responsive version for this as we have a separate mobile version of this website based on Mobile jQuery.. **So please only take desktop version into consideration**" :)

Comment: `<article>, <section>, <header>, and <footer>` markup implementation a good tip.

Comment: @MaryMelody I read that, but people not using phones resize their browser windows. A good design should be able to withstand that.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Have a look at this page and see how a very similar structure is handled responsively: http://mainecoonadoptions.com/adopt.shtml  -- it's all done with css, no JS. It does take a bit more work to figure out page layouts, but you then don't have to maintain a separate mobile site and you don't have to worry if the viewer has a massive screen!

Comment: @ialarmedalien,  I agree with you other site i am doing as responsive website & have recently done two using Foundation 5 layout. but this client requirement and time frame i have is very little. so priority is to work with desktop version.. In case in future that comes as a request hopefully i only need to make changes to css.

Answer (score 1):

Footer & copyright sections are not showing up because you have a floated element above them in the page. So they are actually just sitting behind all the floats.

So a simple `clear: both` will bring out these two footer elements. Either add some height eg `height:10px` or some text so you can see them.